# DialogFlow Integration with Twilio depreciation

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot, twilio-api

There is a notification showing up on when you go to integrate dialogflow with other platforms like Twilio, Skype etc.. that it will be shudown by April 2020 and moved to open-source. 
What is the reason or advantage? Thanks for any guidance in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason basicaly, but may be Dialogflow has to mentation all the thirdparty.
Suppose if twilio do some changes in there APIs dialogflow has to adopt those and make changes accordingly.

So now they want us to be not dependent on one click integration rather they [open sourced](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations) the code of those integration.

Here are the example, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations